# Renaming all files with part of subfolder name using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, rename, subdirectory

I have a main folder, with many subfolders, and many files within those subfolders. I would like to add the suffix of the subfolder to the prefix of every file within the subfolder. I would then like to export all files within all subfolders, with the new prefix, to a new general folder to be bulk uploaded into a platform.

Before:
C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\ is main folder, within this main folder there are many subfolders
C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\JOHN_DOE_12345, within these subfolders I have many files
C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\JOHN_DOE_12345\contract.pdf
C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\JOHN_DOE_12345\confidentialityagreement.pdf ...

After:
C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\JOHN_DOE_12345
C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\JOHN_DOE_12345\12345_contract.pdf
C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\JOHN_DOE_12345\12345_confidentialityagreement.pdf

The number of characters will always vary for the subfolder names, but I figured I could somehow look specifically for the number after the second "_" to add as prefix.

I have VBA below that has been working great to at least rename the files with the folder name, but now I need to alter to only grab the number after the second "_" and also then move the files into a general folder.

Any help would be appreciated!

Below macro is used in Excel where in cell A7 I have the main folder path.

```
Sub doIt()
' Add reference: Tools->References->Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim fldMain As Folder
Dim fld As Folder
Dim fil As File
Dim file_path As String

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
   
    ' Main folder that contains the subfolders
    Set fldMain = fso.GetFolder(Range("A7").Value)
   
    ' Loop through subfolders
    For Each fld In fldMain.SubFolders
            ' Loop through files in the subfolder
            For Each fil In fld.Files
                With fil
                    ' Rename the file in the subfolder
                    .Move fld.Path & Application.PathSeparator & fld.Name & "_" & .Name

                End With
            Next fil
    Next fld
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Files

- This will not modify the source files.
- It will copy them renamed to the destination folder.
- Make sure that the code works correctly before you replace `.Copy` with `.Move` to move them.
- Adjust the worksheet name `Sheet1` and the cell holding the destination path `A8`.

```vb
Sub CopyFiles()
    ' Add reference: Tools->References->Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' ADJUST!
    
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
   
    ' Get the source folder (object).
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = CStr(ws.Range("A7").Value)
    If Not fso.FolderExists(sFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The source folder """ & sFolderPath & """ doesn't exist.", _
            vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim sFolder As Folder: Set sFolder = fso.GetFolder(sFolderPath)
    
    ' Get the destination folder path (string).
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = CStr(ws.Range("A8").Value) ' ADJUST!
    If Not fso.FolderExists(dFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The destination folder """ & dFolderPath & """ doesn't exist.", _
            vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sSubfolder As Folder
    Dim sFile As File
    Dim sDelimiterPosition As Long
    Dim ssName As String
    Dim dPrefix As String
    Dim dPath As String
    
    ' Do it.
    For Each sSubfolder In sFolder.SubFolders
        ssName = sSubfolder.Name
        sDelimiterPosition = InStrRev(ssName, "_")
        If sDelimiterPosition > 0 Then ' subfolder has delimiter
            dPrefix = Right(ssName, Len(ssName) - sDelimiterPosition)
            For Each sFile In sSubfolder.Files
                dPath = fso.BuildPath(dFolderPath, dPrefix & "_" & sFile.Name)
                sFile.Copy Destination:=dPath ', OverWriteFiles:=True ' default
            Next sFile
        'Else ' subfolder doesn't have delimiter; do nothing
        End If
    Next sSubfolder

End Sub
```

Comment: this worked great! However, now I'm running into the issue where in some instances, there is another subfolder structure within the subfolders (and sometimes even another one within that). Is there a way for the macro to look through ALL subfolders to file the files and then rename according to very top level of subfolder? For example Parent folder>Subfolder Layer 1 with name>Subfolder layer 2>Subfolder layer 3>Files to be renamed with the name from subfolder layer 1